# Click and open a new page based on the clicked element data

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in web development and I am practicing my fundamental html, css and javascript skills.

I have here a code snippet of a blog-like site that I am doing as practice. I am fetching the data on **https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts** and **https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users**  to put in the site. In the code below, you can see how I fetch the data and how do I put them. I also put a photo of the site itself.

I just want to ask a few questions.

1. You can see in the code that the **title** and the **content** is in **anchor tag**. I want to ask if, just using vanilla javascript, there is a way I can click the **title** or **content** of the post and it will open to a new tab and it will only show that post? I think I know how to do this in Vue.js using router-link and props, but I am practicing and I am wondering if this is doable using only plain Javscript.
2. If you look in the **article** tag in the HTML, it is quite long. So instead of doing a lot of `document.createElement` and `.appendChild`, what I did was I wrote the entire **article** tag in the HTML. Then in the `setPost` function, I just selected and cloned it using `.cloneNode(true)` and from there, I just changed the contents based on the post in the for loop.  I want to ask if this is a good way to do this or should I just manually create and append elements? How would you do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => {
    // console.log(res);
    if(res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    }
    return Promise.reject(res); 
  })
  .then(data => {
    // console.log('data: ', data.slice(0, 3));
    const posts = data.slice(0, 3);

    setPost(posts);
    // getNavLink();
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err))
  
function setPost(posts) {
  const main = document.querySelector('main');
  const article = document.querySelector('article');
  const loading = document.querySelector('#loading');

  for(post of posts) {
    const clone = article.cloneNode(true);    
    const title = clone.querySelector('.article-title');
    const author = clone.querySelector('.author');
    const body = clone.querySelector('.article-content');
    const date = clone.querySelector('.date');

    title.href = `#${post.title}`;
    // title.target = '_blank';
    title.textContent = post.title;
    body.textContent = post.body + post.body + post.body + post.body;
    date.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString();

    (() =>           fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${post.userId}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      author.textContent = data.name + ',';

      clone.classList.remove('display');
      loading.remove();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)))();

    main.appendChild(clone);
  }
  
  article.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class='container container-flex'>
    <main class='main-content'>
      <div id='loading'></div>
        <article class='display'>
          <div class='article-head'>
            <a href='#walapa' class='article-title'></a>
            <div class='article-details art-flex'>
              <span class='author subtitle'></span>
              <span class='spacer subtitle'></span>
              <span class='date subtitle'></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='article-body'>
            <a href='#' class='article-content'></a>
          </div>
          <div class='article-spacer'></div>
        </article>
    </main>
    
    <aside class='sidebar'>
      Tags
    </aside>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the click event on the title then inside your event function you make use of the window.open() method.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```js
let hello=document.getElementById("hello");
hello.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  window.open(url of where you are fetching the dat)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood my question #1 because of my statement. What I am asking there is this: I click to a post  and I want to go to the post's page in my website. Like in facebook or twitter, you click in a post and you go to that post's page. Or in stackoverflow where you click a question and you go to that question's page. I can't find a way to do that. I don't know how to pass the post's data to other HTML page using plain javascript.

Comment: if that is the case, you can wrap your H and P tags in A tags and set the href to the id of where you want to go.